# Moving files with a certain extension using grep

Tags: linux, command, line

I'm trying to move files with the .txt extension.

```
ls /original/file/path | grep .txt
```

This successfully lists the files with txt extension. However when I do the following:

```
mv `ls /original/file/path | grep .txt` /the/new/path
```

I get an error that says:

```
mv: cannot stat 'test.txt': No such file or directory
```

Is there any reason I'm running into this error?

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`. It's errorprone, and unneeded. Just `mv *.txt /the/new/path`

Comment: I apologize - I should have mentioned that this will be in a script so I can't just use the mv command. I have to find the files first then move them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for that I would use `find`:

```
 find /original/file/path/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt'  -exec mv {} /the/new/path/ \;
```

explaining the parameters:

- look for files in `/original/file/path/`
- only on the current folder (`find` will go deep in the tree if you want)
- with the name `*.txt`
- and execute the command `mv` replacing `{}` by each file found.

Comment: Won't it work also without `\;` sequence at the end?

Comment: @Albi93 it wouldn't. `-exec` expects the command to terminate either with `;` or `+`. Tried it and got `find: missing argument to '-exec'`

Answer (score 1):

That's because ls into a directory would remove the path from the file, ie the original path is stripped from the filename. So mv command is actually looking for test.txt in the current directory, hence the error.

You can make use of wildcards,

```
mv `ls /original/file/path/*.txt` /the/new/path
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to simply use mv and a wildcard *.txt to match all of the text files like

```
mv /original/file/*.txt /the/new/path
```

but if you really must to use grep you can pipe it to mv with xargs like

```
ls /original/file/path | grep .txt | xargs -I% mv % help/
```

Using the I flag for xargs says that you are going to use the following character to specify where to pipe the files and I use the % character. However this should only be used if you for some reason need to use grep or ls but it quite often can have errors.